# what is the meaning of backslash in /etc/security/limits.conf

Tags: linux, pam, open-files, sysctl

`/etc/security/limits.conf` looks like this

```
#<domain>      <type>  <item>         <value>
#

#*               soft    core            0
#*               hard    rss             10000
#@student        hard    nproc           20
#@faculty        soft    nproc           20
#@faculty        hard    nproc           50
#ftp             hard    nproc           0
#@student        -       maxlogins       4

# End of file
\* soft nofile 20000
\* hard nofile 22000
```

as I remember the backslash should not set before `* soft nofile 20000`

so I not sure if backslash meaning is to ignore the line or just ignore the star (*) wildcard ?

Comment: The manpage of limits.conf don't say anything about this `\` syntax .... i'm pretty sure this file is f*cked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, and to my quick reading of the [source code](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/master/modules/pam_limits/pam_limits.c), a backslash has no special meaning here. Since `\*` is not a range, does not start with any of the recognized special characters `@%`, and is not the exact string `*`, the domain is interpreted as a user name. Note that the user name is `\*`, not `*`.

This is just a mistake in the file, possibly a bug in a script used to generate the file. The intent was presumably to write `*` (meaning all users) instead of `\*`.

Comment: Possibly someone ran a `sed` substitution on the file, replacing `#*` by `\*` (thinking `*` needed escaping in the replacement text). Shrug.